# Move all elements after a selected li element to the start using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Is it possible to move all elements after a selected li element to the start using jquery.
For example, if i select 3 from the li below.

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

the result

```
<ul>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll().prependTo('ul');
});
```

Comment: here is the link to `nextAll` documentation for future visitors - https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: I think `$(this).nextAll().prependTo($(this).closest('ul'));` will make it more generic

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it should work as expected

```js
// Set a click event listener
$("ul").on( "click", "li", function() {
  // The first element in the ul list
  const first = $("ul li:eq(0)");
  
  // The current element - the element you clicked on
  const current = $(this);
  
  // The current element's index (starts from 0)
  const currentIndex = current.index();
  
  // Total amount of ul items
  const totalCount = $("ul li").length;
  
  // Loop from the current element position + 1 to the last one
  for (let i = currentIndex + 1; i < totalCount; i++) {
    const next = $("ul li:eq(" + i + ")");
    
    // Insert the clone of next element before first one
    first.before(next.clone());
    
    // Remove the original of the next element from the list
    next.remove();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```